# How to use Fancybox only on element id group

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get Fancybox to only look at the images inside a particular element id. I have a page that has divs in it that each have a unique id like so :

```
<div id="p23152" class="post bg2">
```

The problem when I fire fancybox on a page at the moment it grabs a thumbnail from every picture on the page, which can be hundreds.

So what I want to do exactly is if someone clicks on a picture which belongs to a div with a unique id, I want fancybox to include only those pictures in that divs id, not as well as every other div as it does now.

Comment: can you provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dkinzer solution looks good, however if you have ten or more `<div>` then you would need to set a different fancybox custom script for each of them.

Assuming that all the `<div>` share a common class (`class="post"` for instance as in your example) then you could do this to separate each gallery for each `<div>` in a single script like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".post").each(function(){
  $(this).find("a").attr("rel", this.id).fancybox();
 });
}); // ready
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BwuaT/3/)

Comment: For some reason this method only loads the first picture I press on, If i click on the fancybox to load the next or previous image it comes back with an error saying "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later". Then if I close fancybox and open the picture that failed it works for that picture but again will not load previous or next. The method given by @dkinzer works properly though. So why is yours failing? I would prefer not to load a different script for each div like you said.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that these images are loaded using a php download.php file. I didn't think that would be an issue since it works with the old fancybox method I used as well as the method described by @dkinzer. If I replace the dynamically loaded images with dummy static ones in the php script, your method then works. Strange.

Comment: Ok great I got this to work. the problem was there were other images in the div, like those used for buttons etc that your method was also picking up. So I changed find("a") to find(".thumbnail a") to make the targets more specific. Cheers dude.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit it by using the appropriate selector:

```
$("div#p23152 a").fancybox();
```

Look at the Fancybox [Tips & Tricks](http://fancybox.net/blog) page for more details.

Comment: This works, thanks dkinzer. I'll use this for now and on the side see if I can get the method described by @JFK to work, so the accepted answer may change.